# WPGlobus - language http redirect error

Tags: php, wordpress, http

Instead of using apache i use this php to redirect language on http server language

```
$langs=explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
if(!is_array($langs))$langs=array($langs);
foreach($langs as $l){
    $reallang=(strlen($l)>2)?strtolower(substr($l,0,2)):strtolower($l);
    if(!class_exists('WPGlobus'))break;
    $currentlanguage=WPGlobus::Config()->language;
    /*echo "Testing browser lang $reallang<br>Current language is $currentlanguage<br>";*/ //DEBUG
    if($reallang==$currentlanguage)break;
    foreach(WPGlobus::Config()->enabled_languages as $lang) {
        if($lang==$reallang)header("Location: ".WPGlobus_Utils::localize_current_url($lang));
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that i cant access my admin panel because it changes the URL. How can i set this only to work in front end?

Answer (score 1):

Check for `is_admin()` and `! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' )` before running your code. Then you'll be sure you are not in the admin area.